# RoboScript not able click Enable Location OK button in Firebase Testlab

Tags: android, firebase, android-gps

I am trying to test an Google Map based Android app using RoboScript on Firebase TestLab. By default location is disabled on TestLab devices. To enable them we need to simulate a click on OK button on the system prompt. But this click never happens. You can see the screenshot below. The OK button never gets pressed and flow stops here.

[image: screenshot]

I checked the RoboScript json file. Android studio never recorded the OK button click. I tried to create another element like below. But couldn't identify what should be the resourceId for the system dialog.

```
    {
        "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
        "timestamp": 1512127956674,
        "replacementText": "",
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "canScrollTo": false,
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "com.entransys.parkeze:id/confirm_linear",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
            "resourceId": "android:id/content",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "com.entransys.parkeze:id/action_bar_root",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      }
```

So my question is
a) Is there an option to make location enabled before the test starts on the device in Firebase TestLab ?

b) Is there an option to generate clicks on the system level dialog using Robo Script

Edit 1: Added screenshot

Edit 2: Yes, there is confusion between if the ok button is getting pressed or Ok button got pressed [location icon is appearing in appbar] and map is not visible. There is no error and flow stops here.

Comment: Facing the same issue? Have you got any solution?Please suggest.

Comment: Facing the same issue? Have you got any solution?Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I am recording the robo script for my app. It never recorded the actions performed on runtime permissions.